# Manipulating elements of a matrix, to loop or not ?

Tags: matrix, manipulate, list-manipulation

I have a grid of values generated from a MATLAB evaluation. Most of these elements are 0, some 0.5 and the remainder 1. I'd like to write a mathematica script which reads in the CSV and then, in every position where there is a  1, I'd like it to create a Graphics3D red sphere of radius 1, and in every position where there is an 0.5, a green sphere of radius 1. However, I'm not sure whether the best approach is to use loops or something more natural in Mathematica. To illustrate, here's a sample 5 x 5 matrix;

```
M = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5}, {1, 0, 0, 0, .5}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5}, {1, 0,
 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
```

I can get all the ones and halfs from the grid as follows;

```
Ones = Position[M, 1];
Halfs = Position[M, 0.5];
OneLength = Length[Ones];
HalfLength = Length[Halfs];
Xpos = Part[Part[Ones, 1], 1];
Ypos = Part[Part[Ones, 1], 2];
```

Where I get the lengths in case I need to run a loop - which I'm trying to avoid. Similarly the Xpos and Ypos give a co-ordinate I could loop but I'm sure there's an easier way. In essence, I want to end up with a picture like this for the sample data above;

[image]

In the example above, I generated it manually using

```
j1 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Green, Sphere[{5, 6 - 1, 0}]}];
j2 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Green, Sphere[{5, 6 - 2, 0}]}];
j3 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Green, Sphere[{5, 6 - 3, 0}]}];
j4 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Green, Sphere[{4, 6 - 5, 0}]}];
g1 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Sphere[{1, 6 - 2, 0}]}];
g2 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Sphere[{1, 6 - 4, 0}]}];
g3 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Sphere[{3, 6 - 4, 0}]}];
g4 = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Sphere[{5, 6 - 5, 0}]}];
Show[j1, j2, j3, j4, g1, g2, g3, g4]
```

Notice that I've subtracted the y element from 6, as Matlab starts its y-count from the top down rather than from the axis, so any matrix I get in from Matlab will need something like this to Y-flip. Is there a clever way to automate this, using table or otherwise which will circumvent loops? If loops are required, what is the most efficient way of creating one? I will eventually be working with 200 x 200 arrays so manual manipulation would be best avoided! Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your manual version has eight spheres, while the matrix only has seven non-null entries. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Map`, you can avoid looping:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5],
 {Red, Sphere /@ (Position[M, 1] /. {x_, y_} :> {x, 6 - y, 0})},
 {Green, Sphere /@ (Position[M, .5] /. {x_, y_} :> {x, 6 - y, 0})}}]
```

or a little shorter (but more nerdy):

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5],
 {#1,Sphere/@#2}&@@{#[[2]],Position[M,#[[1]]]/.{x_,y_}:>{x,6-y,0}}&/@{{1,Red},{0.5,Green}}}]
```

With some more options, you get your desired 3D-view:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5],
 {#1,Sphere/@#2}&@@{#[[2]],Position[M,#[[1]]]/.{x_,y_}:>{x,6-y,0}}&/@{{1,Red},{0.5,Green}}},
 ViewPoint->Above,ViewVertical->{0,0,1},Boxed->False,AxesOrigin->{0,0,0},
 Axes->{True,True,False},AxesLabel->{"x","y","z"}]
```

[image: 3D-view]

Comment: Brilliant - cheers!

Comment: @DRG: Glad to hear to have been of some help!

Answer (score 6):

The `MapIndexed` function works very nicely for this, as it provides both the value of the array element, and a list representing its position. I wasn't golfing here, so I used pattern matching on function arguments for the rest:

```
draw[0, _] = {};
draw[v : Except[0], {x_, y_}] :=
  {v /. {0.5 -> Green, 1 -> Red}, 
   Sphere[{x, 6 - y, 0}]};

Graphics3D[{
  Opacity[0.5],
  MapIndexed[draw, M, {2}]}]
```

Comment: +1. `MapIndexed` seems the most appropriate tool. I might use `Condition` with numeric tests, esp. since the data is coming from outside *Mathematica*.  E.g. `draw[zero_, _] /; zero == 0 :=...` and `v /. {v0_ /; v == 0.5 -> Green, v0_ /; v == 1 -> Red}`. (For instance `1` matches only the `Integer` and not the `Real` number 1, and the numbers might be off by machine epsilon or so. Using `Equal` allows for such differences.)

Comment: Great answer, will use this technique for something else I have in mind! Thanks